# Does my application need a connection pool if backend database is NoSQL (Azure Cosoms DB)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, connection-pool

I am very new to NoSQL world and wondering how connections are managed by NoSQL databases like Azure Cosmos DB.

I am designing a highly scalable solution for real-time application. And one of the concern is how to manage numerous connections/requests to Azure Cosmos DB from Azure Functions or my business tier?

Is Cosmos DB subjecting to similar limitations as SQL Server is in terms of number of available connections?

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions connections limitation allied to all outbound connections irrespective of target service. Some services might optimize the connection usage (pooling, multi-plexing etc...) for higher concurrency and throughput.

Specifically for CosmosDB: 2.0.0-preview package has connection multiplexing and pooling, please check  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/2.0.0-preview

NOTE: Azure functions V2 run-time is required for custom CosmosDB SDK version.